# API Facebook - Post on a page (appearance)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im using the api from facebook to post in my fan page but... i have a problem

If I paste the URL in the textbox in Facebook the appearance of the post is pretty nice but when i do from the API...

```
$args = array(
    'message' => $data['title'],
    'description' => $data['title'],
    'caption' => 'www.DIR.domain',
    'link' => get_permalink($pid)
);
```

Here you can see the difference, isn't the same post, but if i do with the same, the post posted from the API have the same appearance of the right and if i only paste the url to the textbox have the appearance of the left

[image: 1]

what can i do to get the same result (the left..) posting via API?

Comment: Have checked the facebook share button code..

Comment: what? im talking to post from wordpress to facebook with the api and is for post to a FAN PAGE, not in my wall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook handles feed postings via API in a different way, because they are not made directly by a user. There is nothing you can do, except for using an image as large as possible:

perfect: 1200x630px or bigger, minimum: 600x315px, aspect ratio 1.91:1.

It also depends on several other parameters afaik (how many likes/comments there are, how famous and reliable the domain is, ...)

In other words, this is a feature and app postings are considered more spammy than user postings so they usually get less visible.